# What is the area bounded by the graph of $ \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor =2 $ with the $x$ and $y$-axis?

Tags: graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Question: If $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$, then the area bounded by the graph of $ \lfloor  x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor =2 $ with the $x$ and $y$-axis is?
Answer provided: $3$ units$^2$.

My doubt: How do we graph this relation in order to find the area?

Comment: The question makes no sense.  If $x, y \le 0$, so are their floors, so the sum cannot be $2$ or any number greater than zero.  Did you mean $-2$ on the right?  Or $x,y \ge 0?$

Comment: Extremly sorry I meant greater than or equal to. Will make the edit. Sorry once again @RossMillikan

Comment: It is still not a function.  The points $(\frac 32, \frac 32)$ and $(\frac 32, \frac 54)$ both satisfy the equation, so it fails the vertical line test.  The set of points for which the equation is satisfied is a series of unit squares, three of which are in the first quadrant.

Comment: @Viraam, did you perhaps mean "graph this formula" or "graph this relation"?

Comment: Ohh yes, it isn't a function. I'll make an edit right away.

Comment: @Χpẘ Yes. I've changed it from function to relation

Comment: It's still strange that a question is asking to find the area "bounded by the graph of" something which is a region, not a curve.

Comment: You don't need to add in the "units${}$^2$" in the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out, the "graph" of the relation is not a one-dimensional curve but a series of non-overlapping regions. Presumably the question is about finding the area of the regions in the first quadrant.

If $x,y\ge0$, then also $\lfloor x\rfloor,\lfloor y\rfloor\ge0$ and so $\lfloor x\rfloor,\lfloor y\rfloor=0,1,2$ are the only possible values.

First consider $\lfloor y\rfloor=0$ (i.e. $0\le y<1$). We have $\lfloor x\rfloor=2$, that is, $2\le x<3$; hence we have the unit square
$$\{(x,y):2\le x<3,0\le y<1\}$$
Similarly $\lfloor y\rfloor=1$ gives rise to the unit square
$$\{(x,y):1\le x,y<2\}$$
and $\lfloor y\rfloor=2$ to the unit square
$$\{(x,y):0\le x<1,2\le y<3\}$$
These squares are non-overlapping; hence the total area is $3$.

Answer (score 5):

$\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\lfloor y \rfloor$ are nonnegative integers. So find the pairs of nonnegative integers $(A,B)$ so that $A + B = 2$. For each such $(A,B)$, find the set of $(x,y)$ values for which $\lfloor x \rfloor = A$ and $\lfloor y \rfloor = B$.

The result isn't a curve. For $(A,B) = (1,1)$, the set of all $(x,y)$ values is every point inside the square with bottom left corner $(1,1)$ and top right corner $(2,2)$. The square includes the bottom and left boundaries, but none of the top and right boundaries.

Comment: Ohh ok. So we need to find squares like that for which points inside them satisfy the given relation? @jkabrg

Comment: @Viraam It ends up like that, yes.

Comment: So for $(A,B) =(0,2) $ the square's bottom left corner is $(0,2)$ and the top right corner is $(1,3)$. Similarly for $(A,B) =(2,0) $ the bottom left and top right corners are $(2,0)$ and $(3,1)$. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

When I graph via Desmos, [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3qc6vjlnqt), the area is 6. Note that the points $(0,3), (1,3), (1,2), (2,2), (2,1), (3,1), (3,0)$ are not part of the bounded area but are all arbitrarily close to it. (In other words $(2,2)$  isn't part of bounded area, but $2-\epsilon,2-\delta$ (for arbitrarily small positive $0<\epsilon,\delta<1$) is.) Along with the point $(0,0)$ they outline the area.

---

EDIT

Thanks to input from GFauxPas and AkivaWeinberger, I contend that the upper boundary looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Ww8NYQs_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=high) (image created by AkivaWeinberger), with the upper boundary "open" in the sense that $(2,2)$  isn't part of relation, but $2-\epsilon,2-\epsilon$ (for arbitrarily small positive $0<\epsilon<1$) is. This assumes $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, which isn't specified in OP.

IMO, this leads to ambiguity in determining whether the area occupied by the relation is to be included in the area bounded by the relation, the x-axis, and the y-axis. There are 4 possibilities I see:

1. $x,y$ are real And area bounded by relation (series of diagonally linked squares) is to be included in area asked for in OP.
2. $x,y$ are real And area bounded by relation is not to be included in bounds in area asked for in OP.
3. $x,y$ integer, which makes relationship a curve without area.
4. $x,y$ real, And interpret conditions as saying what is the area of the relation in Quadrant I. In other words the OP saying $x,y$ axis are boundaries i meant to bound the relation, not the area. That interpretation makes the condition $x,y \ge 0$ redundant, but nonetheless the use of "with" instead "and" lends weight to this interpretation.

Since OP says answer specifies an area of $3$, that would eliminate #1, but assuming the answer a priori isn't ideal.

Bottom line: question needs clarification.

Comment: This is wrong. See my answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. Is the answer provided incorrect? Or is the answer actually 3?

Comment: @Viraam are $x,y$ real numbers or integers or something else?

Comment: @Χpẘ Nothing as such is specified in the question. Hence, I'm not really sure. Does that affect the solution?

Comment: @Viraam, yes it matters.

Comment: @GF did you look at the graph? As an example, if $0<\epsilon<1$ is an arbitrarily small number then points like $(1-\epsilon,3-\epsilon),(2-\epsilon,2-\epsilon)$, are all part of the area under the graph (assuming $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @jkabrg Did you look at the graph I linked to? Also note that $x,y$ are not defined to be integers in OP. Therefore if $x=1.9999,y=1.99999$, then $⌊x⌋+⌊y⌋=2$ and $(1.9999,1.99999)$ is part of the area under the graph.

Comment: @GF thanks for pointing out that error. My response to you is a more general way of saying what I *meant* to say in the earlier comment. BTW, did you look at the graph I linked to?

Comment: I looked at the graph and I'm saying the graph is wrong. This relation doesn't define a 2-dimensional curve, it's a region.

Comment: @GF, what is the distinction you are making? The OP doesn't say "2-dimensional curve", it says the area bounded by x-axis, y-axis, and the given relation.

Comment: What is the Desmos graph a graph of? It's *not* a graph of $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor = 2$.

Comment: @GF you can see the formula in the column on left: "$\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)+\operatorname{floor}\left(y\right)=2$"

Comment: The program tells you that there is a problem graphing it. Consider the point $P = (1,1)$, which satisfies the equation but is not on the graph. Desmos's graph is wrong. We're going in circles, I'm done here.

Comment: @GF, I see what you are saying. In effect the upper boundary of the graph is 3 squares (versus a curve), with their lower left corners at $(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)$. So the area bounded by the relation

Comment: Desmos's graph there is incorrect; it seems to be some sort of bug. The point $(1.5,1.5)$ satisfies the equation $\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor y\rfloor=2$, and yet it's not on the graph. Desmos seems to be having a problem with this specific input. I recommend testing the equation on various other half-integer points to understand what the actual graph should be.

Comment: @Akiva I think the correct graph of the relation is a set of squares which are diagonally linked and centered around the line $y=3-x$. The upper boundary (which is what's drawn) is "open", in the sense that $2,2$ isn't part of relation, but $2-\epsilon,2-\epsilon$ (for arbitrarily small positive $\epsilon$) is. My theory is that because my input is an equation, Desmos "wants" to draw a curve, rather than a series of squares.

Comment: [Here's the actual graph](https://i.imgur.com/Ww8NYQs_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=high)

Comment: @Χpẘ Yup. (I got the above image through messing with Desmos's inequality capabilities…)

Comment: @Akiva, exactly what I was thinking, with the upper boundary "open". So what would you say the area bounded by that relation and the two axis is? Seem ambiguous to me.

Comment: @Χpẘ I think whoever designed the question must have been confused.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger my apologies. Corrected.

Comment: very confused and incorrect, that's why I gave a downvote

Comment: @GCab what's incorrect? I give the same two answers as you did, based on 4 different interpretations of the questions.

Comment: @Χpẘ: incorrect is hypothesizing  $x,y$ be integer and speak of curve

Comment: @GCab did I miss something in OP that said $x,y$ were real? If $x,y$ are integer then there is a curve.

Comment: @Χpẘ:  ".. then there is a **set of points**"

Comment: @GCab What are you quoting? Those words don't appear in OP or in any of OPs comments. Additionally, $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ doesn't preclude there being a set of of points.

Comment: @GCab it appears as though your reasoning for your downvote is faulty. Obviously your choice to downvote even if you have no legitimate reason, but not in spirit of MSE

Comment: @Χpẘ: I do not want at all that my critics be interpreted against the spirit of MSE. I tried and withdraw the downvote, but I am no longer allowed to do that unless your answer changes. In any case consider it withdrawn.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  = a\quad  \Rightarrow \quad a \leqslant x < a + 1
$$
and therefore
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor  = 2 \hfill \\
  0 \leqslant \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor ,\left\lfloor y \right\rfloor  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant a \leqslant x < a + 1 \hfill \\
  0 \leqslant 2 - a \leqslant y < 2 - a + 1 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\
   \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer}\;a \leqslant 2 \hfill \\
  a \leqslant x < a + 1 \hfill \\
  2 - a \leqslant y < 2 - a + 1 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Therefore the answer $3$ refers to the area of the region 
defined by the condition ${\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor  = 2}$
**in itself**.
$$
\begin{gathered}
  R = \left\{ {(x,y):\;\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor  = 2} \right\}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \int\limits_{\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor  = 2} {dxdy}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,a\, \leqslant 2} {\int_{x = a}^{a + 1} {\int_{y = 2 - a}^{2 - a + 1} {dxdy} } }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,a\, \leqslant 2} 1  = 3 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

The area bounded by the given condition and the $x$ and $y$ axes will be instead
$$
\begin{gathered}
  S = \left\{ {(x,y):\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \;0 \leqslant \text{integer}\;a \leqslant 2 \hfill \\
  0 \leqslant x < a + 1 \hfill \\
  0 \leqslant y < 2 - a + 1 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\quad } \right\}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \int\limits_S {dxdy}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,a\, \leqslant 2} {\int_{y = 0}^{2 - a + 1} {dy} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,a\, \leqslant 2} {\left( {2 - a + 1} \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = 3 + 2 + 1 = 6 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$